# calling a void method from another class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.3

I have two classes: `MainClass` and `SecondClass`. I have imported `SecondClass.H` to `MainClass.m` to use some of the methods in there. I'm able to call a method with a double type input but I can't (or do not know how to) call a method that does not have (or void type) input.
I am able to call the method with double type by the command: `[self.second someMethod2: type double];`I have tried to call the void input method by using: `[self.second someMethod1];` but that does not work.

I have these two methods in a different class.

-(void)pushOperand:(double)operand {

```
NSNumber *operandObject = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand];

[self.operandStack addObject:operandObject];
```

}

-(double)popOperand {

```
NSNumber *operandObject = [self.operandStack lastObject];
if( operandObject ) [self.operandStack removeLastObject];
return [operandObject doubleValue];
```

}

I'm able to use the first method

[self.brain pushOperand:[self.display.text doubleValue]];

but xcode cannot even find the second method. I've tried

[self.brain popOperand];, [self.brain popOperand];, ...

Comment: Should have worked. What error are you getting?

Comment: Please, tell me you aren't trying to storyboard this!

Comment: What's the error? Your code seems fine.

Comment: Xcode just cant see the method. "No visible @interface for SecondClass declares the sector someMethod1"

Comment: yes I'm using storyboard... is there a problem?

Comment: With that error message you normally just have to #import the .h file of the class the compiler can't see.

Comment: Have you moved your SecondClass to any other folder from where it was originally created?

Comment: This code is from iPad and iPhone Application Development by Paul Hegarty at Stanford university, some very good videos I am currently working my way through them this is how I recognized the code. If you keep watching the videos he details how to solve issues in the code you are working with, and how to improve it so you don't get it again.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have two classes, ClassA and ClassB.

**Important note, in the interface file of ClassA takeNothingAndReturnNothing must be declared as protype like  `-(void)takeNothingAndReturnNothing;` so that it becomes public**

In the `ClassA` you have an instance method called `takeNothingAndReturnNothing`(name shows tha the method is void) and the method declaration is like below

```
-(void)takeNothingAndReturnNothing{
   NSLog("this is %s from ClassA",  __FUNCTION__);
}
```

in `ClassB` (after importing `ClassA`) first create an object of `ClassA` and later call its instance method like below..

```
ClassA *theObject=[[ClassA alloc]init];
[theObject takeNothingAndReturnNothing];
```

Comment: that seems like it's what I have... I'll post my code in parts.
I have these two methods in a different class


- (void)pushOperand:(double)operand {
    NSNumber *operandObject = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand];
    [self.operandStack addObject:operandObject];
}

- (double)popOperand {
    NSNumber *operandObject = [self.operandStack lastObject];
    if( operandObject ) [self.operandStack removeLastObject];
    return [operandObject doubleValue];
}

Comment: The only problem is that when he storyboards, he needs a valid reference across both VC's, which means dragging an NSObject into the storyboard file... Ugh, the anti-patterns are giving me chills.